# What is the main difference between anonymous authentication and using an anonymous credential?

Tags: authentication, protocol-design, anonymity

What is the main difference between anonymous authentication and the use of an anonymous credential? And when we should use them?

Comment: Do you mean "anonymous credentialing"?

Comment: It is going to be tough to answer your question because it is not clear what you mean.  Authentication is a process, but a credential is not.

Comment: @Patriot thanks, I mean anonymous credentials scheme, some paper discussed it, e.g., https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep590a/11wi/slides/CSEP590a-anoncredsv3.pdf but I am confusing, what is the difference it with anonymous authentication